# In a backbone.js app, where should I put an event tracking tag for "visited site"?

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application, mixpanel

I'm using Mixpanel, and I need one general event anytime anyone visits the site. Basically it should fire once per 'hit', or be the same as a visit in Google Analytics.

I tried adding it to my index.html file, but the problem was it seems to fire many more times than one per visit.

My sense is to put it in my `App.start();` function. Is this a good place, or where would be the best place to put the event tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code into your view

```
initialize: function() {
        this.$el.off();
    },
```

Resource: https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template/blob/master/js/views/home/HomeView.js